# Docker SSL working on container but not accessible in host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, docker

Currently I have laravel project on my docker instance.

But the problem is,

SSL accessible only for that container and I can check it using this command

`curl --insecure https://127.0.0.1:4021/api/login`

And this gives me my api response like this

[image]

Which is correct and working fine only if I try to curl it inside the container.

Now I'm trying to check if that curl is accessible to my docker host

using this command

`curl -k -v https://MY-HOST-DOCKER-IP:4021/api/login`

but this gives me an error like this

[image]

What could be the reason why this error keeps showing?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `curl -k -v https://MY-HOST-DOCKER-IP:4021/api/login` in your container to ensure your service is listening 0.0.0.0:4021

Comment: This is the error I get if I try to use that command in the host `curl: (7) Failed to connect to MY-HOST-DOCKER-IP port 4021: Connection refused`

Comment: Please check the updated question to see the result of your suggestion

Comment: Think now you need to find the config file for your service in your docker container and then you have 2 options: edit it to move server ip address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 or to edit or create your docker file and then you stop your current container and start brand new one from the new docker file

Comment: First option is useful anyway: it helps to proof the concept. The second one is the best one: with your docker files you can expose service to the World (if you really need it)